# How to properly call an ActionResult with parameter which return a view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, actionresult

I have this code which returns a view:

```
public ActionResult Survey(int idProject, string name)
{
    return View(Surveys.Data.Services.Project.GetAllSurveys(idProject));
}
```

When I call this from client with

```
@Url.Action("Survey", "Project", new { idProject = project.IdProjet, name = project.Nom })
```

The url appear with parameters **?idProject=2&name=work** which I have been told is not the correct way to work in MVC.

I don't think an ajax call would be of good use here since I return a view to the client.

So how should I call this ActionResult Survey?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following to you `RouteConfig.cs` file before the default route

```
routes.MapRoute(
  name: "ProjectSurvey",
  url: "Project/Survey/{idProject}/{name}",
  defaults: new { controller = "Project", action = "Survey" }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a url like Survey/Project/2/work, then you need to modify your route value like,

```
 routes.MapPageRoute("Default",
    "{controller}/{action}/{idProject}/{name}",
    "new { yourcontroller, youraction, UrlParameter.Optional, UrlParameter.Optional");
```